# How to arrange the data in columns and rows by making a box?

Tags: arrays, go, box

I want to know, how to make a box in Golang that will contain multiple rows and columns like this

```
┌────────────┬─────┬────────┐
│ Name       │ Age │ Score  │
├────────────┼─────┼────────┤
│ John Smith │ 30  │ 99.223 │
│ Jane Smith │ 30  │ 99.223 │
└────────────┴─────┴────────┘
```

Although there is a library for it, that is called [olog](https://github.com/da0x/olog) but it is not a good option for large datasets.

The second point is that it does not support arrays to be used in a `struct` like I have asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73677359/how-to-print-the-data-in-a-frame-using-an-array). In this case, if I have many variables, not just name, age, and score, it will not allow me to write each variable in a struct using an array.

Is there any other library or a way to write the data in columns and rows?

Comment: Is there anyone to guide me?

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't very clear. Do you wish to keep an array of objects in memory, or to write them somewhere (a file for instance)?

Comment: @Sangam The data is saved in mysql database. I am just fetching and using it to show it in box.

Comment: ok, so you want to print to console. And does it have to be via olog, because you do what you need using fmt.Printf() within a loop. Populate the array of objects first, and keep a track of the max width of each variable (so that you know what offset to use when printing the delimiter).

Comment: @Sangam I tried to use olog by using array in the struct but it was giving me `invalid field name dt.TicketHeading[1] in struct literal`. You can see my post for details that has a link in the question already.

Comment: @Sangam I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: I don't think this can be done using the library you mentioned. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you can do this using fmt.Printf() within a loop.

Comment: @Sangam I know that it is not possible using the `olog` library. That's why I am asking for another way.

Comment: [text/tabwriter](https://pkg.go.dev/text/tabwriter) should be able to do this, except maybe the horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

You might try/test a more complete option with [`Evertras/bubble-table`](https://github.com/Evertras/bubble-table)

[image: bubble-table]

It does not infer anything from any struct though, which means you need to loop over your own array, and call

```golang
// Note that there's nothing special about "ID" or "Name", these are completely
// arbitrary columns
columns := []table.Column{
  table.NewColumn(columnKeyID, "ID", 5),
  table.NewColumn(columnKeyName, "Name", 10),
}

// For each row:
rows := []table.Row{
  // This row contains both an ID and a name
  table.NewRow(table.RowData{
    columnKeyID:          "abc",
    columnKeyName:        "Hello",
  }),
```